# three.js, position of renderer border?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Scene code from [Aerotwist](http://www.aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/).

```
var $container = $('.container');
var width = $container.width();
var height = $container.height();

var view_angle = 45,
    aspect = width / height,
    near = 0.1,
    far = 10000;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( view_angle, aspect, near, far);
```

My question is what are the coordinates of the border?
If I add a sphere at `(0, 0)` I see it in the centre of the screen, but what if I want to put it in the top right hand corner?

```
    sphere.position.x = width/2
    sphere.position.y = height/2
```

This sends the ball way off the screen...

I think its to do with the camera position, so how to I set the camera such that I have the right border at `width/2` and top border at `height/2`

Comment: I think you are missing some stuff here and confuse 3D Space and 2D Browser space which is a totally different thing.
It would be easier to answer you if you would tell what you want to achieve in general. by setting renderer.setSize you can define the size of the 3D window. But there is no easy relation between the 2D Browser space and the 3D space your sphere is in. what you can do is set the camera.position so that you can approximately position your sphere. Anyhting else and more accurate you will have to do some projection from 2D Browser space to 3D world space, i think

Comment: I think you might be right, I will look into it further.